# Typecasting an array in C

Tags: arrays, c, ffmpeg, casting, macros

I was reading FFMPEG source code on extracting audio and I found these macros. What do these macros do?

```
#define REINTERPRET_CAST(type, variable) C_CAST(type, variable)
#define STATIC_CAST(type, variable) C_CAST(type, variable)
#define C_CAST(type, variable) ((type)variable)

//used like this
int value = 0;
int sampleIndex = 0;
uint8_t* buffer = calloc(50, sizeof(uint8_t));

value = REINTERPRET_CAST(uint8_t*, buffer)[sampleIndex];
value = REINTERPRET_CAST(int16_t*, buffer)[sampleIndex];
value = REINTERPRET_CAST(int32_t*, buffer)[sampleIndex];
value = REINTERPRET_CAST(int64_t*, buffer)[sampleIndex];
int ret = STATIC_CAST(float, *REINTERPRET_CAST(double*, &value));
```

Comment: Run the code through the preprocessor and see what the macros expand to.

Comment: They just expand to the same ordinary explicit casts. They authors likely defined them to mirror the semantics of C++ casts and/or document the reason why the casts are well defined.

Comment: Assuming I'm not missing anything, these macros are simply useless, and just writing the casts by hand would probably be easier for everybody.

Comment: I'm a noob. Forgive me for asking. How would I write these macros by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> //used like this

Used like in this code they do nothing meaningful - convert pointer to int and assign to int vartable (abstracting from the wrong syntax)

If they are used like this:

```
uint64_t value = *REINTERPRET_CAST(int64_t*, buffer + sampleIndex);
```

BTW the macro is wrong as well

```
#define C_CAST(type, variable) ((type)(variable))
```

Then it is called pointer punning and it invokes Undefined Behaviour violating strict aliasing rules.

It should be done this way:

```
#define pune(var, X) _Generic((var), \
              uint16_t *: pune16, \
              uint32_t *: pune32,  \
              uint64_t*: pune64  \
              )(var, X)


uint16_t pune16(uint16_t *val, const void *ptr)
{
    memcpy(val, ptr, sizeof(*val));
    return *val;
}

uint32_t pune32(uint32_t *val, const void *ptr)
{
    memcpy(val, ptr, sizeof(*val));
    return *val;
}

uint64_t pune64(uint64_t *val, const void *ptr)
{
    memcpy(val, ptr, sizeof(*val));
    return *val;
}
```

example usage:

```
void foo(void *v)
{
    uint32_t x;
    x = pune(&x, v);
    printf("%"PRIu32"\n,",  x);
}
```

Comment: "It should be done this way" lacks taking `[sampleIndex]` into account.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica  `buffer + sampleIndex` doesn't it ?

Comment: Hmm, OP's `[sampleIndex]` involves pointer addition of the target type.  `buffer + sampleIndex` is pointer addition at the source type.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I do not know what are you talking about `buffer` is definitely the source

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica you could simple say that the original macro is bad instead of those comments

Comment: `REINTERPRET_CAST(uint64_t*, buffer)[sampleIndex]` is like `((uint64_t*) buffer)[sampleIndex]` and that access a differ part of `buffer[]` than `pune64(buffer + sampleIndex);`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica you are commenting not existing code - your comment came many minutes after my edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251821/discussion-between-chux-reinstate-monica-and-0).

Comment: why not just `memcpy(&x, v, sizeof x)`?

Comment: @tstanisl have you not seen `memcpy`?

Comment: I mean that there is no need to play `_Generic` and `puneN` functions. Only `memcpy` would be sufficient.

Comment: @tstanisl no because it has to work with pointers as well. Too much writing. Compiler will remove redundant assignments anyway